# Ruby: wrong argument type nil (expected Data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm getting the error:

```
wrong argument type nil (expected Data)
```

Here's my code (names have been changed to protect the innocent ;) ):

```
old_foos.each do |foo|
  foo.bars.each do |old_bar|
    if new_foo.bars.any? {|new_bar| new_bar.name == old_bar.name} #assume new_foo is properly set
       check = 1
    end
  end
end
if check == 1
  do_something!
end
```

I have a nagging suspicion that this is a scope issue, but I'm not sure. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The goal here is to check if a user is submitting any `foos` that have a `bar` property that already exists. I apologize for the vagueness, but this is the best I can do.

Comment: Do you have a line number for the error?  Might help narrow it down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of your foos (old or new) doesn't have any bars... and then you call each (or any?) on it... you'll be calling each on a nil object. That may be the issue. 
But a line-number would certainly help. Can you get a full stacktrace?